# processEvent is not called after dispatching an event

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton

If I dispatch an (action) event to a `JButton`, the `processEvent` method of the button will not be called.

In the example below, I thought that following steps will be executed

1. `b1` dispatches the event to `b2` (`dispatchEvent` is called)
2. `b2` processes the event `(processEvent` is called)
3. `b2` executes its action listeners

But step 2 and 3 will not be executed. Can anybody explain why?

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final JButton b2 = new JButton("b2") {
      @Override
      public void processEvent(AWTEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("action event will be processed" + evt.toString());
        super.processEvent(evt);
      }
    };

    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("b2 clicked");
      }
    });

    final JButton b1 = new JButton("b1");

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("b1 clicked");
        final ActionEvent e2 = new ActionEvent(e.getSource(), e.getID(), "Redispatch-Event");
        b2.dispatchEvent(e2);

      }
    });

    panel.add(b1);
    panel.add(b2);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `b1` will process it

Comment: Can you explain *why* the code is overriding `processEvent`? It's not something I've found a need for, in over 15 years of Java GUI programming.

Comment: In fact `b2.doClick()` will probably do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i think in event source should be `b2` and use `postEvent()` instead.

Comment: @jackjay Except postEvent is deprecated :P

Comment: Based on what I can understand, the `ActionEvent` doesn't actually get processed by the queue, instead, it's processing the `MouseEvent`'s which in turn are generating the `ActionEvent`, probably from the `ButtonModel` (based on observation)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have to modify a code that uses the processEvent as hook to show a confirmation dialog for certain inputs

i've already tried b2.doClick(), but processEvent is not called, only the action listeners

Comment: I don't think processEvent will be notified of ActionEvent, it's not a system event (like MouseEvent/KeyBoardEvent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to send the button a `MouseEvent`:

```
MouseEvent e2 = new MouseEvent(
    (Component)e.getSource(), MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e.getWhen(), 0, 1,1, 1, false );
```